# Change .svn folder to another location in Tortoise SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Is there a way to change the `.svn` folder to a different path, outside of the project's folder?

This is because I don't want to include this folder in my local and cloud backups.

Today my project's folder structure is like that:

- Project folder: `C:\myproject`
- SVN folder: `C:\myproject\.svn`

What I want is something like this:

- Project folder: `C:\myproject`
- SVN folder: `C:\otherfolder\.svn`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer: Every SVN working copy of a repository has an .svn directory in the root directory of the working copy.

The .svn directory indicates that it is an SVN working copy. Without this directory you just have an export of your SVN repository as all SVN tools require the .svn directory to work.

Comment: Too bad then, the .svn folders are space hungry and will bloat my backups... Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Most Backup and cloud tools allow to exclude certain folders from sync/backup. BTW: Is your SVN server so unstable that you need a copy of the workspace?

Comment: I use Dropbox as a cloud backup service, and unfortunately they don't have an option to exclude subfolders. My SVN server is not unstable, but it never hurts to have more backups ;)